# How can I make requirejs polymorphically load a module?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, cordova-3

I am currently developing a single page application using Cordova 3.4.0, Requirejs and Backbone. While porting my application from iPhone to iPad, I need to change some functions in some views and keep other parts intact.

To keep the change minimal, my solution is to create new object for each view I need to change, inherit all properties from original view and override only necessary functions.

To do so, I need to configure Requirejs so that in iPad, if I require, for instance, '*user/view/edit-profile.js*', it will check whether there was a '*user/ipad/view/edit-profile.js*' file, if there is one, requires it, otherwise require '*user/view/edit-profile.js'*.

I have tried i18n, but it is not right for this situation. I am coming up with an idea of creating a new plugin for requirejs to do the task.

**Does anyone have any suggestion for my problem?**

*Btw, Since the required file changes dynamically according to the platform. I call it polymorphism.*

Answer (score 1):

You could use [path fallbacks](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks):

```
paths: {
    "user/view/edit-profile": ["user/ipad/view/edit-profile", "user/view/edit-profile"]
}
```

The above will make RequireJS try to load the `ipad` variant first. If as you develop your application you end up with logic to complex for fallbacks, you can use [errbacks](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks):

```
function onload(module) {
    // Whatever you want to do...
};

require([module_a], onload, function (err) {
    require([module_b], onload);
});
```

The code above will try to load a module from `module_a` and then from `module_b`. I use this kind of code to load modules with names that are computed at run time.

Comment: Thank your for your help. However, my context is we have completed our iPhone application and it is a huge project and was tested carefully so we don't want to touch the source code of current well-running iPhone application. It makes us cannot use your second suggestion.


In your first suggestion, we have to search for all required modules and set its path together with appropriate fallbacks in config file. It will make the matter of adding more module complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Since every module is a Backbone View, I come up with a solution, which will override extend function of Backbone View to return modified object depending on the existence of ipad, iphone or android dependencies.

The solution will require that if a base view have iPad version, it have to declare the iPad versions at dependencies, the extend function will extend existing view by the iPad view so that the iPad view can inherit all properties of base view and override only necessary functions.

I name the view PolyplatformView. Each view need to declare its ID, for example: user/view/edit-profile

```
Backbone.PolyplatformView = Backbone.View.extend({
});

Backbone.PolyplatformView.extend = function() {
    if(arguments[0].moduleId) {
        var extendPropsPath = arguments[0].moduleId.replace('/', '/' + constants.platform_name + '/'); 
        // turn user/view/edit-profile -> user/ipad/view/edit-profile

        if(require.defined(extendPropsPath)) {
            _.extend(arguments[0], require(extendPropsPath));
        }

    } else {
        console.warn('No module Id in polyplatform view -> cannot extend its parent');
    }
    var extended = Backbone.View.extend.apply(this, arguments);

    return extended;
}
```